# Picking a training set from the larger application set

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis on a dataset.But there is no existing corpus that my classifier can be trained on that is similar to the dataset that I want to analyze. My question is as follows: Can I use a randomly sampled subset of this data for training/validation phases and then use the trained classifier for performing analysis on the larger dataset? I plan to introduce some variability by adding data points to the training set that are similar to the application dataset but not from that set. Is this is a valid approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the standard procedure of cross-validation. During cross-validation you split your data on (let's assume) 80%-20% training testing data and make 5-10 (depending on the size of data you have) different splits. So I would suggest that you keep a subset of the data and then perform cross-validation on this subset. This is the optimal way to train your model.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I thought cross-validation would be the correct approach too. Just to clarify, you are suggesting that I perform cross-validation on my subset and use the rest of my data as the "unknown" dataset that I would want to analyze?

Comment: Exactly. Do not perform cross-validation on the entire set, or else you will over-fit your model.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks!